# Varnish Cache and Magento: Guru Meditation and 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: magento, varnish

I recently activated the varnish cache module for my Magento store, this worked pretty well, no problems. Now I copied the code and the DB of this Magento installation and placed it somewhere else on the same server to create a testing environment. I deactivated varnish cache on that testing environment by setting **system/varnishcache/enabled** to 0 and **system/varnishcache/disable_caching** to 1.

The problem now is, that I always get:

*Error 500 Internal Server Error

Internal Server Error

Guru Meditation:

XID: 628339795*

No matter what I do, I cleared the cache, reloaded, tried different browsers, activated the varnish cache module, doesnt help. Any ideas what else I could try?

Thanks!

Comment: try to see your php or other error logs what causes the 500 error it is logged

Answer (score 2):

By default Mageto switches errors output off. If your php is configured not to log php errors web server will send 500 error in case any fatal error occurs.

You can check errors in /var/log/exception.log and /var/log/system.log or enable output of all errors in your magento installation:

edit your index.php :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

and .htaccess:

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"
```